# Migrating older external project history to JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

After reading lot of forums, i am still not cleared about this migration issue.

I am planning to mirage my whole older projects issue history to JIRA.
I am flexible of having my old records in CSV or JSON or SQL.

So my query is by using JIRA import from CSV, or import from JSON technique, can we import per CSV file which contain  a numbers of project, each project is repeated or new  one, and each projects with different issue histories?

Else I had bunch of csv files, some of the csv file pointing to same projects and some be unique different project with different issues.
So now how to automate to import these csv files to JIRA?
Is there any API's to import?
Is there and coding way to automate import of multiple csv files to JIRA?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried asking on the [Atlassian Q&A](https://answers.atlassian.com) website?

Comment: There is a pretty comprehensive How To here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/importing-data-from-csv-185729516.html

Comment: Yes the conversation is going on with Atlassian's, not get a clear way yet.